# connect client to server using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a node.js basic server as follow:

app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
config = require('./config/config');

var app = express();
require('./config/express')(app, config);
var server = require('http').Server(app);
server.listen(config.port,function () {
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
});
module.exports = server;
```

my port is 8001.

and a deafult.ts file:

```
import express = require('express');
var server = require('../../app');
var router = express.Router();

export = function (app) {
app.use('/', router);
};

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('index', {
  title: 'hello world'
  });
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("connected" + socket.id);
});
```

I have another project, my client and i want to open a socket connection to the server, but i failed to do so.
all examples i've seen using an index.html file inside the node project (indeed works).
i tried adding my client:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<div>
<button ng-click="io.connect('http://localhost:8001')">hi</button>
</div>
```

but i don't get the "connected" log .

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This client should give you a persistent socket connection :

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect(http://localhost:8001);
    // attach your events here
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @xSirase, but when i tried this i dont get the "connected" log i want in my console, i get a lot of thie msg:                                                                                           [grunt-develop] > GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYqXtQM 404 12.745 ms - -                                                                                            and i don't understand why.

Comment: You're looking at your chrome console, not your node.js terminal?

Comment: im looking at my node terminal. i tried to add to my server instead of log, emit event:                                                                        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('message', 'You are connected!');
});:                                                                                                                                        and to my client:    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        alert('The server has a message for you: ' + message);
    })                and get no alert :(

Comment: ,i did some debug. when i use the io in app.js, it is working. so the problem is how to use the server properly outside app.js? it seems my export is wrong.